# Skeleton code: character pointers struggles

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, character

So this is part of a skeleton code which reads this csv file:

```
year,month,day,location,mintemp,maxtemp
2015,4,28,18,6.7,12.9
2015,4,28,22,12.7,19.1
2015,4,29,18,7.6,15.3
2015,4,29,22,13.4,21.9
2015,4,30,18,7.3,21.8
2015,4,30,22,13.2,23.2
2015,5,1,18,9.4,15.9
2015,5,1,22,16.1,27.2
2015,5,2,18,8.7,16.3
2015,5,2,22,14.2,21.4
```

This function reads the file as a string and somehow separates it and puts it into a structure named 'D' of type csv_t.

The structure & others:

```
typedef char input_line_t[LINELEN+1]; 

typedef struct {
    input_line_t labelstring;
    char *labs[MAXCOLS+1];
    int nrows;
    int ncols;
    double vals[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
} csv_t;
```

The function:

```
void
read_csv_file(char *fname, csv_t *D) {
    FILE *fp;   /* used to read from a named file */
    input_line_t line;
    int cols=0, rows=0, bytes=0;
    int c, i, j, chr, ncommas, empties=0;
    double x;
    double nan = 0.0/0.0;

    /* first argument on commandline should the data file name */
    if (fname==NULL) {
        /* and it wasn't there... */
        printf("No csv file specified on commandline\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* try and open the named file for reading */
    if ((fp=fopen(fname,"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error: unable to open %s\n", fname);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* file is open, can now use fp to access CSV data,
       start by reading the bytes of the header row */
    while ((c=getc(fp)) != '\n') {
        D->labelstring[bytes++] = c;
    }
    D->labelstring[bytes] = '\0';

    /* now process line again, breaking in to separate labels by
       replacing commas by nulls, and tracking the start of each of
       the column headings */
    D->labs[cols++] = D->labelstring;
    for (i=1; i<bytes; i++) {
        if (D->labelstring[i]==COMMA) {
            D->labelstring[i] = '\0';
            D->labs[cols++] = D->labelstring+i+1;
        }
        if (cols>MAXCOLS && i<bytes) {
            printf("Too many columns, limit is %d\n",
                MAXCOLS);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    D->labs[cols] = NULL;

    /* ok, that's the labels sorted, now for the data */
    while ((chr=getc(fp)) != EOF) {

        /* there is another row, because first character of it
           just got read, next step is to get the rest of them */
        i = 0;
        line[i++] = chr;
        ncommas = (chr==COMMA) ;
        while (((chr=getc(fp))!=EOF) && (chr!='\n')) {
            line[i++] = chr;
            ncommas += (chr==COMMA) ;
        }
        line[i] = '\0';
        if (ncommas!=cols-1) {
            printf("Data input error line %d\n", rows+2);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* then process the line from the right end */
        j = i-1;
        for (c=cols-1; c>=0; c--) {
            /* look for next previous comma */
            while (j>=0 && line[j]!=COMMA) {
                j--;
            }
            /* access the value */
            if (sscanf(line+j+1, "%lf", &x) == 1) {
                D->vals[rows][c] = x;
            } else {
                D->vals[rows][c] = nan;
                empties++;
            }
            /* mark the new end of the string */
            line[j--] = '\0';
        }
        rows++;
        /* check to make sure don't overflow array */
        if (rows==MAXROWS) {
            /* time to stop reading data */
            printf("Too many rows, truncated at %d\n", MAXROWS);
            break;
        }
        /* if not full, go round and see if there is another data row */
    }

    /* either input has all been read or array is full */
    printf("file %s:\n    %d columns and %d rows of data\n",
            fname, cols, rows);
    if (empties) {
        printf("    %d entries were empty or non-numeric\n",
            empties);
    }
    /* finish building the structure */
    D->nrows = rows;
    D->ncols = cols;
    return;
}
```

I mostly get what's going except from this point onward and also this point particularly:

```
D->labs[cols++] = D->labelstring;
        for (i=1; i<bytes; i++) {
            if (D->labelstring[i]==COMMA/*=','*/) {
                D->labelstring[i] = '\0';
                D->labs[cols++] = D->labelstring+i+1;
            }
```

The last bit of code is very confusing. The labelstring is a string, yet numbers can be added to it. What does it do? How does that give the number of columns. If I get this, I can  understand the whole code. Help is appreciated.
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple actually. Lets say you have `labelstring` containing the string `"Foo"`, then it would look something like this in memory

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'F' | 'o' | 'o' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
^
|
+-------------+
| labelstring |
+-------------+
```

In other words,`labelstring` points to the first character in the string.

If you then do `labelstring + 1` you get the *second character:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------+
| 'F' | 'o' | 'o' | '\0' |
+-----+-----+-----+------+
      ^
      |
      +-----------------+
      | labelstring + 1 |
      +-----------------+
```

It's called *pointer arithmetic*.

And yes you can use it on arrays as well, because arrays decays to pointers to their first element.

After knowing the above, it's also easy to understand that `array[X]` (for any array or pointer `array` and for any `X`) is the same as `*(array + X)`.

And to really blow your mind, thanks to the [commutative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of [addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition), the last bit means `*(array + X)` is equal to `*(X + array)` which leads to `array[X]` being equal to `X[array]`.

Comment: Mind blown when I read the last bit. Anyway, why does labelstring still work without the '*'? I understand the arrays are pointer constants, but dont understand how it works without the asterisks...unless the arrow(->) is the replacement for asterisks?